# Replace / remove highlighting in Jupyter Notebook with custom theme

Tags: css, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

It's clear that the selection is for readability, but it seems too glaring to me.

[A set of themes for Jupyter](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)

How can I edit the configuration and change the transparency or the color of the selected area (blue) or invert the selection to the bracket, or completely remove it? In css syntax I do not understand at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS selector for matching brackets is `div.CodeMirror span.CodeMirror-matchingbracket`

So, you can change the colour of the bracket itself and the background colour of the bracket by putting the following code into your `custom.css` file (`~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`)

```
div.CodeMirror span.CodeMirror-matchingbracket {
    color: #INSERT-YOUR-DESIRED-BRACKET-COLOUR-HERE ;
    background-color: #INSERT-YOUR-DESIRED-BRACKET-BACKGROUND-COLOUR-HERE ;
}
```